# Creating a Button in Excel, that calls upon a created Access query

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

Is there a way to create a button in Excel that runs a query, that is already created, in Access, and then updates the excel spreadsheet using the data from the query? I've searched the web for directions on how to do this, but have only found answers that create a button in Excel, that only runs a query in Excel, not Access. I am assuming this will be done by coding, upon click, in VBA, but have yet to find anything that does this. So... Is it possible? If so, how?

Okay, so I have kind of updated this with question, because I sort of used both options made. So I first created a Function in a Standard Module (Because we may use this later for another sheet in the workbook, and we didn't want to duplicate work):

```
Function GetSqlServerData(sQuery As String, sRange As Range)

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String

    ' Create the connection string.
    sConnString = "NMS"

    ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Open the connection and execute.
    conn.Open sConnString
    Set rs = conn.Execute(sQuery)

    ' Check we have data.
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ' Transfer result.
        Sheets(3).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ' Close the recordset
        rs.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
    End If
    ' Clean up
    If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```

Then I tried to use said function:

```
Sub GetPermits()
    Dim sQuery As String
    Dim sRange As Range

    Set sQuery = "Select * From Customer;"
    Set sRange = Sheets(3).Range("A2")

    GetSqlServerData(sQuery, sRange)

End Sub
```

But it gives me an error right at the spot where is actually use the function. I don't need it to go to a MsgBox, and I don't need it to print it out, all I need is for it to put in the data into the sheet noted on the function call. BTW, the function needs some tweeking, I know. Right now, I just need it to call the darn thing, lol.

Here is a Screen Shot of the error message: If you cant see it, it says, "Compile Error: Expected:=" and it highlights the "GetSqlServerData(sQuery, sRange)" in red. So it must have something to do with that. I just can't figure out what it is.

[Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mF0R8.jpg)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. As a first step I would recommend to search for "Excel vba connect ADODB access database run query" This should get you starting.

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have? You should be able to link directly to the Access query and return it as a table to a worksheet, using either MSQuery or Get and Transform (a.k.a. Power Query). Then all you need to is use the Refresh button to update it.

Comment: @Rory: Right, this is probably the better and easier way to go for the OP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Excel - UPDATE record in ACCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221766/vba-excel-update-record-in-access)

Comment: Sorry but what are you doing. If you use VBA and write soimething like that `Set sQuery = "Select * From Customer;"` and sQuery is a string then you have not understood the basics.  Also `GetSqlServerData(sQuery, sRange)
` cannot work. Again, you make basic errors here. My expectations were higher. Please have a look [here](https://www.homeandlearn.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example for a solution with VBA using ADODB one could use the following function to connect to the database.

```
Function ConnectToDB(ByVal fileName As String)

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection

    If Dir(fileName) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Could not find file " & fileName
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim connectionString As String

    ' https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/
    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" _
                       & fileName & ";Persist Security Info=False;"

    conn.Open connectionString

    Set ConnectToDB = conn

End Function
```

And if you want to copy data from the database one could use the following code. You need to have a sheet with the codename shRepAllRecords

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReadFromDB()

    ' Get datbase name
    Dim dbName As String
    dbName = <fule filename of the database>

    ' Connect to the databse
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = ConnectToDB(dbName)

    ' read the data
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim query As String

    ' First example to use an SQL statement
    ' query = "SELECT * From CUSTOMER"

    ' Second example to use a query name defined in the database itself
    query = "qryCustomer"

    rs.Open query, conn

    ' shRepAllRecords is the codename of the sheet where the 
    ' data is written to

    ' Write header
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        'shRepAllRecords.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
        shRepAllRecords.Range("A1").Offset(0, i) = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i

    ' Write Data
    shRepAllRecords.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    shRepAllRecords.Activate


    ' clean up
    conn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Although if the query is in Access, it might be easier to use `DAO` rather than `ADO`.

Comment: @Zack: Feel free to add an answer with code for DAO.

Answer (score 1):

Dependent on your requirements, you could have this without VBA in a quicker and more reliable way, to have a table that is pointed at your query, that updates when you click Refresh.

To do so, in Excel navigate to Data > From Access.

From here, navigate to your database with the saved query, and when asked to select a table, you can select the query instead.

You can also write your own SQL query for Excel to execute against the database instead.

You can edit the connection properties to refresh when the workbook is opened, or refresh when every 60 minutes for example, or you could turn it all off, and allow the user to hit 'Refresh' in Excel itself.

Alternatively, you could setup a button that runs the refresh table command against the linked table, and this would do the same

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

So I was finally able to figure out the issue. I was not putting "Call" in front of the function call. Once I did that, it accepted it. Thanks for all the assistance! The final answer was close to what Storax gave above. So I credited him with the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: You enclose a function's arguments in parentheses when you want to capture the function's return value.  However, your function does not return a value, so nothing to capture, which means you don't need parentheses and then don't need `Call` to eliminate the error from parentheses.  Just call your function like this: `GetSqlServerData sQuery, sRange`